# How to ask someone to take a photo?

Tags: mandarin, translation

Recently on vacation I wanted to ask a Chinese tourist if they would mind taking a photo of my wife and I - but I didn't know how, so just asked `你可以吗? (nǐ kěyǐ ma?)` while pointing to my camera.

How should I ask this in future?

Comment: +1 Good question... Is 可以 a verb?

Comment: I think it is a verb ...

Comment: Yes, technically a modal verb

Comment: This makes no sense to me actually. I expect an action after 可以.

Comment: Well, if I'd known what verb to use I would have used it. But I didn't, so I just said 你可以吗? :P

Answer (score 11):

There are many ways to ask this. Some examples:

- 您能给我们俩照一张相吗?
  *nín néng gĕi wǒ men liă zhào yì zhāng xiàng ma?*
- 您能帮我们拍个照吗?
  *nín néng bāng wǒ men pāi ge zhào ma?*
- 您可以给我们照张相吗？
  *nín kĕ yĭ gĕi wǒ men zhào zhāng xiàng ma?*
- 请问，您可以帮我们照张相吗？
  *qĭng wèn, nín kĕ yĭ bāng wǒ men zhào zhāng xiàng ma?*
- 麻烦您给我们照张相
  *má fan nín gĕi wǒ men zhào zhāng xiàng*
- 麻烦你，帮我们照张相，好吗？
  *má fan nǐ， bāng wǒ men zhào zhāng xiàng，hǎo ma?*

照张相 means to take a picture, so does 拍照（片）。 You can both use 能 and 可以. 帮（助） means to help. 我们俩 means the two of us. 给 is here a proposition.

Comment: You can also invite them to do so (请) or ask if you can inconvenience/trouble (麻烦) them, too. 
I.e. (能)[请/麻烦][你／您] + preposition + noun phrase + 吗.

Comment: 拍个照 is used much more often than 照张相 in my personal experience. 照张相 sounds a bit old fashioned, young people usually say 拍个照. Also, if you're starting a question with 可以, mostly you finish it with 吧?